# How can Parse String of array

Tags: reactjs

"Area_Polygon_coordinates": "[{17.3850, 78.4867},{17.3365, 77.9048},{16.7630, 78.1443}]" To

"Area_Polygon_coordinates": [{lat: 17.3850, lng: 78.4867},{lat: 17.3365, lng: 77.9048},{lat: 16.7630, lng: 78.1443}]

Comment: Your expected structure is invalid

Comment: Updated my question Plz reply now

Comment: well, I believe if you concatenate  '{}' around your string then it will be JSON and you can use JSON.parse(obj) to get your array.

Comment: "obj": "[{17.3850, 78.4867},{17.3365, 77.9048},{16.7630, 78.1443}]"  JSON.parse(obj) error occurs.How to add key through it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
    let obj= "[{17.3850, 78.4867},{17.3365, 77.9048},{16.7630, 78.1443}]" 
    //add "lat" key
    obj=obj.replace(/{/g,'{"lat":')
    //add "lng" key
    obj=obj.replace(/,[^{]/g,',"lng":')
    JSON.parse(obj)
```